# How to send data from one activity to another listview?

Tags: android

Hey guys I'm working on an app in android studio. I have a listview and when I make a selection i would like to add that selection to another listview in a different activity. What is the easiest/best way to do this? I've tried putExtra without any luck. Any examples or ideas would be great. Thank you guys.

Thanks for the examples everyone they've helped me understand a lot better the intent system. I've been trying the different examples everyone has posted and I've kind of gotten stuck. The goal is simply to have the items I select from the listview in the Walmart.java file to show up in the listview in GiftsSelected.java I have another place to open the activity so I don't need it to immediately open the new activity. 
Here is my code:

This is Walmart.java

```
 public class Walmart extends ActionBarActivity {   
     private String[]giftarray = {


        "Apple"  ,
        "Bananas",
        "Bed",
        "Beef",
        "Bottle",
        "Bread",
        "Broccoli",
        "Carrots",
        "Cat",
        "Chicken",
        "Chocolate",
        "Computer",
        "Cow",
        "Crow",
        "Dog",
        "Dolphin",
        "Dove",
        "Drawer",
        "Egg",
        "Fish",
        "Fork",
        "Fridge",
        "Giraffe",

};

Intent a = new Intent(Walmart.this,GiftsSelected.class);

private ListView giftListView;
private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,      ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){}
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){

    return true;
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_walmart);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    giftListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.gift_list1);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_gallery_item, giftarray );
    giftListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    giftListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String item = "Item added to registry";
            list.add(item2);

            a.putStringArrayListExtra("list",list);

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    });

}
```

This is my GiftsSelected.java code:

```
public class GiftsSelected extends ActionBarActivity {

private ListView giftListView;
private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    //This makes my app crash which makes me think I did this wrong...
    list = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("list");

    String[] giftarray = new String[list.size()];

    list.toArray(giftarray);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gifts_selected);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    giftListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.gift_list1);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_gallery_item, giftarray);
    giftListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    giftListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            String item = "Item added to your registry";
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this is the list that i use

```
  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

add elements in it like this

```
  list.add("something");
```

in first Activity

```
Intent i=new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
i.putStringArrayListExtra("list",list);
startActivity(i);
```

in the second activity in the onCreate

```
list = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("list");
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the first Activity is X and X holds a listview that updates another listview in Activity Y.

If X is tightly related to Y, that is to say Y launches X, gets data then immediately returns to Y, then you should use `startActivityForResult` from Y.

```
class ActivityY {
   public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 2;
   ...
   Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityX.class);
   startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);

   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         String returndata = data.getStringExtra("rowdata");
        //update your listView, do notifyDataSetChanged() etc;
      }
     }
    }

}

class ActivityX {

  // in listview onItemClickListener or elsewhere that listens to row click
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  returnIntent.putExtra("rowdata", rowdata); // whatever data you need to transfer
  setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
  finish();       
}
```

If X and Y are loosely related, that is to say X is not necessarily launched from Y, but goes to Y then you should just use the usual `startActivity(intent)`.

if X and Y are completely independent, that is to say X is not necessarily launched from Y, may not go to Y or wanders other Activities before arriving in Y then you should cache the data. If the data size is small then the best way is to store it in [Preferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html). When you Y Activity starts, get the data, update your ListView, then if needed remove the cached data from Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

a)You can make the listview item object parcelable and send it between activities via intent extra.
b)You can save the selected listview item in a global variable.(Not recommended)